# Вислови, що вживають при вирішенні непорозумінь чи конфліктів

Tags: фразеологізми, вживання-слів

Які є в українській мові вислови, що можна вжити при вирішенні непорозумінь чи конфліктів? А саме, запропонувати чи погодитись на примирення.

Приклад з російської  - "мир, дружба, жвачка". Чи є щось таке українською?

UPD: відредагував питання

Comment: Сленговий варіант: "мій косяк".

Comment: my bad – вибач, це я [напартачив](http://sum.in.ua/s/napartachyty)

Answer (score 7):

Теоретично, при заохоченні до примирення або висловлюванні позитивного ставлення до нього, можна вжити одну з наступних приказок/прислів'їв/приповідок:

- Де незгода, там часто шкода.
- З добрими людьми завжди згоди можна дійти.
- Згода (дім/хату) будує, а незгода/сварка руйнує.
- Згода мир звіщає, хто згоди хоче, той згоду має.
- Коли усюди сама згода, здається кращою й погода.
- Краще/ліпша солом'яна згода, як золота звада / золотий суд.
- Ліпше в згоді і любові бідному, як у сварці і ненависті багатому.
- Я до згоди, як риба до води.

Джерело: М. Позаяк, «Прислів'я та приказки: взаємини між людьми» (1991, Київ, «Наукова думка») (АН УРСР, Інститут мистецтвознавства, фольклору та етнографії ім. М. Т. Рильського) — там указані джерела кожної приповідки.

**На жаль, жодна з них (принаймні на мою думку) не відповідає за духом Вашому прикладу «мир, дружба, жвачка». Сподіваймось, хтось додасть ще.**

Answer (score 7):

Стовідсоткового аналога не пригадую, але в деяких ситуаціях можна сказати:

> Кат із тою (тим) `[причина непорозуміння]`, мир?

[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53402/358141.html)

> **кат із ним (ни́ми)**. Уживається для вираження примирення, вимушеної згоди з чим-небудь, невдоволення чимсь, утрати інтересу до
>   чого-небудь; нехай буде так, як є.

Answer (score 3):

Крім вислову "[кат із ним](https://ycilka.net/slovnyk_fraz_view.php?id=11)", вдалося ще знайти такі:

"**[Закопати сокиру війни](http://moodle.ipo.kpi.ua/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=40971)**"

З історичних реалій походить вираз «У Дарфурі закопують сокиру війни» [УМ. – 2010. – № 37. – С. 9], що означає «йти на примирення, припиняти військові дії». Він дієслівний, книжний, широковживаний, середньо-експресивний; виражений підрядним словосполученням; виконує заголовну та асоціативну функції.

"[**Шукати компроміс**](http://old.journ.lnu.edu.ua/vypusk7/n11/tv11-14.pdf)" (і його трансформація "іти на компроміс", ст. 3 ПДФ).

"[**Викурити люльку миру**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83)" (походження, звичайно, від індійського обряду, але досить часто можна зустріти і в нашій мові)

"[**Жити в мирі**](http://sum.in.ua/s/myr)"

Тобто, якщо ви хочете когось закликати до примирення, то можете сказати: "Давай знайдемо/шукати компроміс", "Може закопаємо сокиру війни?", "Давай жити в мирі" тощо.